# How to restrict the types of all methods in a Scala object?

Tags: scala, types, traits

I'm trying to do something that I'm not completely sure that is either possible or makes sense.

I have an abstraction which, in order words, depends heavily on an object to tell which version of a given component is to be used. It goes like this:

```
object ComponentManager {
  def component1Version: ComponentVersion = Component1Version1()
  def component2Version: ComponentVersion = Component2Version3()
}
```

What I want to achieve here is to limited all methods in `ComponentManager` object to conform to the type `ComponentVersion`. I could define a trait to enforce the types, but I don't know in advance how many components will I have. Therefore, I might end up with people adding to the manager object some stuff like:

```
object ComponentManager {
  def component1Version: ComponentVersion = Component1Version1()
  def component2Version: ComponentVersion = Component2Version3()
  def component3Version = objectWithWrongType()  // this is the problematic line
}
```

For the `component3Version`, we have the offending object. It will compile, but I would rather have a compilation error when such a thing happens, because I have some checks that come "freely" with the proper typing.

Again, I don't know how many components will the manager have, so I can't really rely on a trait specifying each and every method type.

I've read about F-bound types / functions / what-not, but still couldn't figure out whether they are / how to make them applicable to my problem.

Any ideas? "Your restraing doesn't make sense" is also a possible answer, I reckon, but I'd like to get some ideas on this regardless.

Comment: When is the full set of components known? Can you declare a manager with some components omitted?

Comment: It is never known. As the system grows, more components are being added. I'm talking in components to simplify, but this is a data project, so each component in, in fact, representing a dataset operation that has been added to the abstraction. About declaring a manager with components omitted, I'm not really sure what that means. One thing is that, each time a component is added, it is already used immediately, so I cannot see how would that improved my helpless situation... lol

Comment: In your situation, it's known all the time, at the time. For a particular version of the system, you know which components should be there.

Comment: Yes, that is fair. What I'm trying to do, at the long run, is to ensure the integrity of my manager object. As other developers come along, nothing prevents them from messing the manager object, other than the review process. I'd also have my users reaching the manager object in order to simply "register" their new dataset, but not meddling with the inner layers of the abstraction itself. I'm sorta concluding I'm in a deadlock here.

Comment: I think you'll be fine with the approach in my answer, where you have to add components to a type.

Comment: Although: how do you envisage this manager to be used?

Comment: I have an executor for each component. The executor knows no implementation - it simply fetches the implementation declared by the manager and runs it. I'm still thinking about how to apply your answer to my case, but I think it will indeed suffice. Although I do not know in advance how many components will there be, your idea of creating an object for each component is probably what is missing in my implementation (that is, I will have several versions for a component, a component runner and a component object itself - the latter is still absent, and is probably the key to solve this issue).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm making the following assumptions:

- When someone creates a manager, they know how many components they need.
- One must declare versions for all components.

Traits have to declare all method names explicitly, so we can't declare methods for components we don't know about. Instead, let's model components as a type:

```scala
trait ComponentManager {
  type Component
  def version(component: Component): Version
}
```

When someone knows what components they need, they can implement a manager:

```scala
sealed trait MyComponent
case object Component1 extends MyComponent
case object Component2 extends MyComponent
case object Component3 extends MyComponent

object MyComponentManager extends ComponentManager {
  type Component = MyComponent
  def version(component: MyComponent): Version = component match {
    case Component1 => Component1Version1()
    case Component2 => Component2Version3()
    case Component3 => Component3Version5()
  }
}
```

Now:

- Returning anything but a `Version` for any component is a type error.
- Forgetting to match a component is a non-exhaustive match warning.